# How to get device rotation for iPhone 7 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, webkit, device-orientation

I want to get the device rotation for (alpha, beta, gamma) for iPhone 7 and higher. For iPhone 6 this works well for me:

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
  console.log(event.alpha);
  console.log(event.beta);
  console.log(event.gamma);
});
```

But for iPhone > 6 this event is not triggered anymore. To be clear, i dont want the device orientation (portrait/landscape), I want the rotation. Best case would be absoulte (calibrated) data.

For Android "deviceorientationabsolute" works well. Is there something similar for the Apple universe?

Thanks & regards,
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution for me was to get the user permission to use orientation like this. After that 'ondeviceorientation' works.

```
function startOrientation() {
  if (typeof DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
    DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission().then(function(response) {
      if (response == 'granted') {
        console.log('granted');
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('not granted');
  }
}

$("#get_permission").click(function(){
  startOrientation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

for get device rotation in all devices better listen on resize window:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(){
if(window.innerWidth <  window.innerHeight){
//portrait
}
if(window.innerWidth >  window.innerHeight){
//landscape
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking for the portrait / landscape orientation. I'm looking for the absolute alpha, beta and gamma values.